# Is there a standard name for this variant of KL divergence?

Tags: machine-learning, kullback-leibler, divergence

Since KL divergence can be decomposed as
\begin{equation*}
D_{\mathrm{KL}}(q \| p) = H(p \| q) - H(p),
\end{equation*}
I wonder if there exists a *weighted* version of KL divergence, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
D^{\gamma}_{\mathrm{KL}}(q \| p) = H(p \| q) - \gamma H(p),
\end{equation*}
BTW, the motivation of this weighted version is that I conjuncture that the weighted KL divergence is highly related to the temperature scaling technique applied in confidence calibration and knowledge distillation tasks.

Some references to temperature scaling:

1. [Distilling the Knowledge in a Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02531.pdf)
2. [On Calibration of Modern Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04599.pdf)
3. [Temperature Check: Theory and Practice for Training Models with Softmax-Cross-Entropy Losses](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=avHr-H-1kEa)

Comment: Interesting question, though note that this version loses at least some of KL divergence's useful properties, namely that $\mathrm{KL}(P||P)=0$.

Comment: @JohnMadden Yes, but the result is still appealing to me. Now $D_{\mathrm{KL}}^{\gamma}(p \| p) = (1-\gamma)H(p)$, which further makes $p$ to be sharp or soft (it depends on $\gamma$, and that is what the temperature scaling do).